# Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x, x >0 \\ x , x \le 0 \end{cases}$ show that $f$ is a continuous injection.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x, x >0 \\ x , x \le 0 \end{cases}$ show that $f$ is a continuous injection.

Starting from continuity for the case $x  \le 0$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta = \varepsilon$. Now $$|f(x)-f(0)| = |x-0|=|x|<\delta = \varepsilon$$

For $x >0 $. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta =\varepsilon$ I have $$|f(x)-f(0)| = |\frac1x-0| = \frac1x < \delta = \varepsilon$$

So $f$ is continuous. For injectivity let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ now when $x >0$ I have $$f(a)=f(b) \\\frac1a = \frac1b \implies a = b$$

For $x \leq 0$ I have $$f(a)=f(b) \iff a=b$$ so $f$ is also injective. Is this a working solution?

Comment: There's something wrong, probably with the problem statement, because $f$ obviously is *not* continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Any function defined on $\mathbb Z$ (with its usual topology) is continuous. (What happens it $x$ and$y$ are integers and $|x-y| <1$?)

Comment: Have you read topology @Hileni?

Comment: @srm99 I have yes

Comment: Please follow the definition, I have used for continuity in my answer and try to prove its equivalency with the other definitions, known to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space such that each one point sets of $X$ is open and let $Y$ be any topological space. Then any function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.

Note that any subset of $X$ is open. The mentioned topology is known as discrete topology on $X$.

Definition of continuity to be used: Inverse image of open set is open.

Given any open set $V$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)=\{ v\in X: f(v)\in V\}$ which is open in $X$. Consequently, $f$ is continuous.

For your example: $\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the usual topology is discrete, therefore, the given function is continuous.

Comment: Is the topology of $\mathbb{Z}$ neccessarily always discrete?

Comment: Not necessarily. However, since you have not mentioned anything. I have assumed "$\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the usual topology". Instead of this, if you give $\mathbb{Z}$ indiscrete or cofinite topology, then the only function, which are continuous are the constant ones. And the function in your question becomes discontinuous @Hileni.